# Como enviar todos os campos do formulário com $.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um form com 2 campos, Usuario e Senha.

```
$.post('recebe.php',{
    `Nome:'Meu Nome'`
    `Senha:'Minha Senha'`
},function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

Existe alguma forma de pegar o nome e o valor dos inputs e fazer POST sem precisar ficar digitando cada atributo e seu respectivo valor?

Comment: Você quer que ele pegue automaticamente os campos em um `form` e use seus `name`s e `value`s como parâmetros para o `post`. É isso? Ou entendi errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que o método [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) resolve o problema:

```
<form id="cadastro">
    <input type="text" name="nome"/>
    <input type="password" name="senha" />
    <button id="btn"type="button">teste</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(' #btn').click(function(){
        $.post( "test.php", $( "#cadastro" ).serialize())
          .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
          });
        alert($('#cadastro').serialize());
    });

});
```

Comment: Caramba cara, você salvou minha vida hehe, Muito obrigado :D